# How I can join two ManyToManyField number to Integer Field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to get the numbers of values in Two ManyToMany Field and compain both to one Integer Field by function (def)

```
class Video(models.Model):
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name='video_views')
    viewers_by_ip = models.ManyToManyField(UsersByIP, default='192.168.0.1', blank=True)
    viewers_count = models.IntegerField('Here I want to get the number of both field')
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep viewers_count on database? You always may get numbers of m2m fields from a queryset

Comment: To render in the template by doing for example `video.viewers_count`

Comment: Do you need a sum of count viewers and viewers_by_ip?

Comment: yes and add them to the Integer Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You many do it without saving sum of count `viewers_by_ip` and `viewers` into database, actually you have to ways.

Make a property method that will calculate it pet each object:

```
class Video(models.Model):

    @property
    def total_viewes_count(self):
        return self.viewers.count() + self.viewers_by_ip.count()
```

Add a annotation to queryset which getting model object for you:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Video.objects.annotate(
    total_viewes_count=Count('viewers')+Count('viewers_by_ip')
).get(pk=<Video's primary key>)
```

in both cases you may use it in template like that:

```
{{ video.total_viewes_count }}
```